# What is the reason of error "cannot extract elements from an object"

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I need to create some request witch will add an json object if it is null:

```
{
    "json_object_1": [
        {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
      *a new object must be added here*
}
```

or add a key-value pair into a nested object if it is not null:

```
{
    "json_object_1": [
        {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "r": 0
        }
    ],
    "json_object_2":[
     {
         "x": 0,
         "x":0,
         *new key-value pair*
     }
]
}
```

I wrote my request but it works only after the first try. After that I get an error: SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object. What is the reason of this error and how can I fix it?

```
    update table 
set json_column = (
case
    when json_column = json_column - 'json_object' then 
    json_column - 'json_object' || jsonb_build_object('json_object', jsonb_build_object('value', 3))
    else jsonb_set(
        json_column, 
        '{json_object}', 
        (select jsonb_agg(elem ||'{"value": 3}')
         from jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'json_object') AS elem))
    end
)
where json_column is not null;
```

Comment: Try enclosing the "minus" part in parentheses `(json_column - 'json_object') || ...` but without some sample data this is nearly impossible to answer

Comment: I added some code samples

Comment: jsonb_array_elements expects an jsonb array (e.g. `[...]`) but as the error says, you are giving it an object (e.g. `{...}`).  Your example is clearly bogus (not syntactically valid) so no one knows what you are really doing.